# error: –std=c++11: No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu

I tried to compile the thread program by using the below commands.But i am getting the error.

g++ –std=c++11 Thread_creation_function_pointer.cc -lpthread
g++ -Wall –std=c++11 Thread_creation_function_pointer.cc -lpthread
g++ std=c++0x Thread_creation_function_pointer.cc -lpthread

Error:
error: –std=c++11: No such file or directory

Can anyone explain how to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

You have copied your commands from a place that at some point in its creation used automatic conversion of hyphens to their longer cousins the "em dash". This is common in word processor programs like Microsoft Word.

The character before your `std=c++11` is a long "em dash" rather than a hyphen and as a result it is not being parsed as an option but is being parsed as a filename instead.

Specifically notice the different lengths of the dash in the command you listed:

- g++ -Wall –std=c++11

Try

```
g++ -std=c++11 Thread_creation_function_pointer.cc -lpthread
```